# Add range of elements to new list in C#

Tags: c#, list

New programmer here. I'm trying to add a range of elements to a new list in C#. This is for a game I'm making in Unity. It's a game based on the old nokia Snake game, where each time the snake eats a fruit it gets longer. This information is stored in a list in my game. Now the thing is I'm trying to create a game element where at a certain point all the nodes from the snake (the tail basically) break away from the snake itself, and the snake has 3 elements remaining (the head, body, and a tail). I got it to work perfectly fine, except for the fact I can't get the range of nodes in the list to transfer to the newNode list for the life of me.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
{
    if (nodes.Count > 3)
    {
        newNodes.Add(nodes[4]);
        newNodes.Add(nodes[5]);
        newNodes.Add(nodes[6]);

        newNodes.AddRange(nodes[3], nodes.Count - 3);
        nodes.RemoveRange(3, nodes.Count - 3);                    
    }
```

When I run the game, the expected behavior works for the `newNodes.Add (individual nodes)`. But what I would like is to see happen is something along the lines of `newNodes.AddRange(nodes[3], nodes.Count - 3);` But that doesn't work. How can I get it so it reads the nodes from 3 or 2 or whatever value to the total nodes in the list. I've been stuck on this for days! Really could use some help/input.

The code above is not complete, it's part of a coroutine actually that should get called after certain criteria has been met. It's just that I wonder if there's any way to do this?

Comment: So you want to remove the tail *Skip(3)* from one list, and add them to another list ?

Comment: Why the `for`-loop? You never use that `int i` (in your posted code)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing it just for demo, i guest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
newNodes.InsertRange(newNodes.Count - 1, nodes.GetRange(3, nodes.Count - 3));
nodes.RemoveRange(3, nodes.Count - 3);
```

If newNodes is empty, you need to make sure to pass 0 as index instead of

```
newNodes.Count - 1
```

Comment: I had to pass 0 instead of -1, but omg, it worked!! It is exactly what I'm looking for!! Thank you so much for your help!! You wouldn't believe how many countless hours I spent on this to figure this out!!!

Comment: please upvote if my answer is helpful for you :)

Comment: I upvoted your answer immediately! But it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." so I hope you get the vote still. I'm sorry I'm new to StackOverflow.

Comment: ah it's ok, try to answer another questions as well, so you will get reputation

Comment: If I can help someone else with an issue I'll definitely do that! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Using the LINQ extension method [Skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip) you can skip over the first part of a list and get the rest. As it is an extension method, you first need this near the top of your code file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then you can use this to add all but the first three items to the new list:

```
newNodes.AddRange(nodes.Skip(3));
```

Note: this doesn't change "nodes" in any way.

Bonus: if "nodes" contains 3 items or less, this will not fail (but of course add nothing to newNodes)

Comment: Neat answer. +1 for the "Note" and the "Bonus".

Answer (score 1):

As said, I'm a new programmer and have never used Stackoverflow. I'm truly overwhelmed by all the responses in such a short time, **thank all** for taking the time to read my question and trying to figure it out with me.

The code that seemed to work in my case was

```
newNodes.InsertRange(newNodes.Count, nodes.GetRange(3, nodes.Count - 3));
```

It basically captures all the nodes (snake bodies) in the list and releases them properly in a new list!

Again thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you use

```
newNodes.AddRange(nodes[3], nodes.Count - 3);
```

you're only providing the single node at index 3.  AddRange expects an IEnumerable, not a single object from a list.  To get an IEnumerable you have to use the GetRange or LINQ methods that have already been posted by others.